# Traverse JSON data when index is in different array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON obj as

```
var myJsonObj = {
                'key1' : {
                    'type' : 'key1 type',
                    'key1-1' : {
                        'type' : 'key1-1 type',
                        'data' : 'key1-1 value'
                    },
                    'key1-2' : {
                        'type' : 'key1-2 type',
                        'data' : 'key1-2 value'
                    },
                    'key1-3' : {
                        'type' : 'key1-3 type',
                        'key1-3-1' : {
                            'type' : 'key1-3-1 type',
                            'data' : 'key1-3-1 value'
                        },
                        'key1-3-2' : {
                            'type' : 'key1-3-2 type',
                            'data' : 'key1-3-1 value'
                        },
                        'key1-3-3': {
                            'type' : 'key1-3-3 type',
                            'key1-3-3-1' : {
                                'type' : 'key1-3-3-1 type',
                                'data' : 'key1-3-3-1 value'
                            },
                            'key1-3-3-2' : {
                                'type' : 'key1-3-3-2 type',
                                'data' : 'key1-3-3-2 value'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

I have an array of index:

```
var index = new Array('key1', 'key1-3', 'key1-3-3');
```

How do I get the data from myJsonObj when indexs are known in index variable ?
I want to fetch the result of `myJsonObj['key1']['key1-3']['key1-3-3']`. How to achieve the output ?

Comment: use `var index = ['key1', 'key1-3', 'key1-3-3'];` instead of Array constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
myJsonObj[ index[0] ][ index[1] ][ index[2] ]
```

Or if you want to allow for a variable number of levels in `index`:

```
var tmpObj = myJsonObj;
for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++)
   tmpObj = tmpObj[index[i]];
```

Note that best practice on initialising an array with known values is to use the square bracket syntax:

```
var index = ['key1', 'key1-3', 'key1-3-3'];
```

And also [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer. Now I have one more question. I need to insert  value as 'key1-3-4': {                 'type' : 'key1-3-4 type',                 'key1-3-4-1' : {                     'type' : 'key1-3-4-1 type',                     'data' : 'key1-3-4-1 value'                 } using index variable at myJsonObj['key1']['key1-3']['key1-3-3'] that also reflects the changes in myJson variable